# APT-OFFLINE is there a way to bypass the initial menu?

Tags: offline, apt, apt-get

I'm trying to automate system updates on some offline Ubuntu systems with a bash script using the APT-OFFLINE tool.  When running (for example) `apt-offline install bundle.zip` it first presents the user with an option menu:

```
(Y) Yes.  Proceed with Installation
(N) No, Abort.
(C) Display changelog
(?) Display this help message.
What would you like to do next: (y, N, ?)
```

Looking at the apt-offline man page, I do not see a "-y" option or something similar to bypass this menu. If I'm just executing the initial `apt-offline install bundle.zip` command in a bash script, how do I have the script automatically enter "y" at the menu prompt and proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  Had a brain drain.  It's a simple answer.

`yes | apt-offline install bundle.zip`